# Drawing three tables with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get what’s not the picture:

[image]

Could you help me to finish it the right way?

code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta} % added arrows.meta
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M) [
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes={
           minimum height = 7mm,
           minimum width = 2cm,
           outer sep=0,
           anchor=center,
           draw,fill=blue!20 % <-added
        },
        column 1/.style={
            nodes={draw=none,fill=none}, % <-- added fill=none
            minimum width = 4cm
        },
        row sep=5mm, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes in empty cells,
        e/.style={fill=black!50}
      ]
      {
        1st Iter & |[e]| & & & & & \\
        2nd Iter & & |[e]| & & & & \\
        3rd Iter & & & |[e]| & & & \\
        4th Iter & & & |[e]| & & & \\
        5th Iter & & & |[e]| & & & \\
        kth Iter & & & & & & |[e]| \\
      };
      \draw (M-1-3.north west) ++(0,2mm) coordinate (LT) edge[|<->|, >= latex] node[above]{Train} (LT-|M-1-7.north east); % changed 5 to 7
       \draw (M-1-2.north west) ++(0,2mm) coordinate (LT) edge[|<->|, >= latex] node[above]{Test} (LT-|M-1-2.north east);

      % dots
      \node [below=3pt] at (M-3-5.south east) {$\cdots$};

      % fold labels and arrows
       \foreach [
             count=\row,
             evaluate={\col=ifthenelse(\row==4, % if fourth row
                                       int(\row+3), % use seventh column
                                       int(\row+1)) % else use column row+1
                       }
                ] \txt in {1,2,3,k}
         {
            \node [below] at (M-\row-\col.south) {Fold-\txt};
            \draw [black!30,line width=1mm,-Triangle] (M-\row-7.east) ++(2mm,0) -- ++(7mm,0) node[black, right] {$E_{\txt}$}; 
          }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not nice to change the question. Wit this you nullify received answer on your original question. If you have some new problem with solution, please ask new question, where you explain, where you stuck in your adoption to new needs.

Comment: Done, I will ask a new one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more for fun. Some node style that types and colors the cells automagically, i.e. this saves you from typing all these `Fold`s (except for the first row).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing} 
\newcounter{Fold}
\edef\LstCol{"green!50","blue!50"}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
Fold/.style={/utils/exec=\stepcounter{Fold}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(mod(\number\value{Fold},5)==int(1+\number\value{Fold}/5)
|| \number\value{Fold}==25,1,0)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{{\LstCol}[\itest]},fill=\mycol,draw,
node contents={Fold \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\number\value{Fold}-1,5)+1)}\pgfmathresult}
},
standard/.style={inner sep=0pt,align=center,draw,text height=1.25em,text depth=0.5em},
decoration={brace}]
 \matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,nodes={Fold},
 row 1/.style={every node/.style={draw,fill=gray!30}},
 column 1/.style={every node/.style={}},
 column sep=1ex,row sep=1ex]
 { |[draw=none,fill=none]| & Fold 1 & Fold 2 & Fold 3 & Fold 4 & Fold 5 \\[1em]
   split 1 &  & & & & \\
   split 2 & &  & & & \\
   split 3 & & &  & & \\
   split 4 & & &  & & \\
   split 5 & & &  & & \\
 };
\node[fit=(M-1-2) (M-1-6),fill=green!50,yshift=1cm,standard] (Trd)  {Training data};
\node[right=0.5em of Trd,standard,fill=blue!50,text width=4cm] (Ted)  {Test data};
\node[fit=(Trd) (Ted),fill=gray!30,yshift=1cm,standard] (Ald)  {All data};
\draw[thick,decorate] ([yshift=-3pt]M.north east) -- ([yshift=3pt]M.south east)
node[midway,right]{Finding parameters};
\node[anchor=north west,standard,text width=4cm,fill=orange] at
(M.south-|Ted.west) (Ted2) {Test data};
\draw[thick,decorate] ([xshift=-2pt]Ted2.south west) -- ([xshift=-2pt]Ted2.north west)
node[midway,left]{Final evaluation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful is what comes to mind ...