# Drawing three tables and two tikz figures

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello fellow and folks!

I need to finish what's on the picture:
[image]

More or less MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,
     standard/.style={inner sep=0pt,align=center,draw,text  height=1.25em,text depth=0.5em}]

    \node[fill=black!20,yshift=1cm,standard] (Trd)  {Training Set };
    \node[right=0.5em of Trd,standard,fill=blue!50,text width=4cm] (Ted)  {Test Set};
    \node[fit=(Trd) (Ted),fill=white!30,yshift=1cm,standard] (Ald)  {Original Set};
    \draw[thick,decorate] ([yshift=-3pt]north east) -- ([yshift=3pt]south east)
    node[midway,right]{};
    \node[anchor=north east,standard,text width=4cm,fill=white] at
    (south-|Ted.west) (Trd) {Training Set -  Validation Set};
    \node[anchor=north west,standard,text width=4cm,fill=white] at
    (south-|Ted.west) (Ted2) {Test set};


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. Where is defined `standard` option for nodes?

Comment: I do not know. I am working on it

Comment: Still not working. Coordinates are not defined :-(

Comment: No worries, pal. I'll figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending,
                calc,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                positioning,
                shadows,
                shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 2mm and 0mm,
    box/.style = {draw, semithick, fill= gray!30,
                  minimum width=#1, minimum height=4ex, align=center,
                  text width=#1-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                  outer xsep=0pt, drop shadow},
   sbox/.style = {signal, draw=cyan, semithick, fill=cyan!30,
                  signal to=east and west,
                  text width=#1, align=center, inner xsep=-3pt,
                  drop shadow},
    arr/.style = {line width=1mm, gray, -{Triangle[angle=60:3pt 2,flex]}}
                        ]
\node (a11) [box=54mm]                  {Training set};
\node (a12) [box=27mm, right=of a11]    {Validation set};
\node (a13) [box=27mm, right=of a12]    {Test set};
%
\path   let \p1 = ($(a11.west)-(a12.east)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        node (a21)  [box=\n1, above=of $(a11.north west)!0.5!(a12.north east)$]  
                    {Training Set};
\node (a22) [box=27mm, right=of a21]    {Validation set};
%
\path   let \p1 = ($(a21.west)-(a22.east)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        node (a31)  [box=\n1, above=of $(a21.north west)!0.5!(a22.north east)$]
                    {Original Set};
%
\node (b1)  [sbox=28mm, below=12mm of a11]    {Machine learning algorithm};
\node (b2)  [box=24mm, rounded corners, fill=olive!30,
             below=5mm of b1]           {Predictive Model};
%
\node [below=of a11.south east,font=\footnotesize, align=left]
      {Training, tuning\\ and evaluation};
\draw[arr]  (b1.east) ++ (2mm,3mm) arc(150:-150:7mm);
%             
\draw[arr]  (a11) -- (b1);
\draw[arr]  (b1)  -- (b2);
\draw[arr]  (a12) |- ([yshift= 2mm] b2.east);
\draw[arr]  (a13) |- ([yshift=-2mm] b2.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**
When I draw an TikZ picture, I do this as follows:

1. Identifying all shapes used in your image nodes and than search in the TikZ and PGF manual, which libraries are needed to drawn them.
2. Define nodes style (by this image code is shorter, concise and more clear).
3. Decide how to draw image (use absolute or relative /preferable/ coordinates for nodes placement, with which node to start drawing the image, etc).
4. Define connection lines style(s).
5. Place nodes.
6. Draw lines between nodes.

Comment: This is to hard for me to draw. I was grabbing examples from [http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/] and trying to make them match with what I want, but it is pretty hard. Thank you very much. Thumbs up times 1000

Comment: @naveganteX, every beginning is difficult. So I decide to add short explanation how I draw TikZ images. It may help you in the next drawing :-)

Comment: I saw it, it'll help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Another proposal, arguably closer to your screen shot. Also it does not need any calc syntax, rather it uses the same tricks as in the [post you may have gotten `standard` from](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492908/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,shadows.blur,shapes.misc,decorations.pathreplacing,
arrows.meta,bending} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily,
     standard/.style={fill=gray!10,inner sep=0pt,align=center,blur shadow,
     draw,text  height=1.25em,text depth=0.5em},
     shadowed/.style={decorate,decoration={
       show path construction,lineto code={
        \draw[#1,gray,opacity=0.5] ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=-0.25ex]\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=-0.25ex]\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        \draw[#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },curveto code={
        \draw[#1,gray,opacity=0.5] 
        ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=-0.25ex]\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=-0.25ex]\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) 
        and ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=-0.25ex]\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=-0.25ex]\tikzinputsegmentlast);     
        \draw[#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        }}}]

    \node[standard,text width=12em] (BL)  {Training Set };
    \node[right=0em of BL,standard,inner xsep=0.5em,densely dashed] (B)  {Validation set};
    \node[right=0em of B,standard,text width=4em] (BR)  {Test set}; 
    \node[fit=(BL) (B),yshift=3em,standard] (L)  {Training Set};
    \node[right=0em of L,standard,text width=4em] (R)  {Test set};
    \node[fit=(L) (R),yshift=3em,standard] (L)  {Original Set};
    \node[below=3em of BL,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle xsep=1.5cm,
    align=center,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!15,thick,blur shadow] (ML)
    {machine learning\\ algorithm};
    \node[anchor=south west,align=left,inner xsep=0.6em] at (ML.north) {Training, tuning, and\\
     evaluation};
    \node[below=3em of ML,rounded corners=2pt,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!15,
    thick,blur shadow] (PM) {Predictive model};
    \draw[shadowed={-Latex,thick}] (BL) -- (ML);
    \draw[shadowed={-Latex,thick}] (ML) -- (PM);
    \draw[shadowed={Latex-,thick}] (PM.30) -- ++ (0,1em) coordinate(aux);
    \draw[shadowed={-,thick}] (aux)-| (B);
    \draw[shadowed={Latex-,thick}] (PM.east) -- (PM.east-|BR);
    \draw[shadowed={-,thick}] (PM.east-|BR) -- (BR);
    \draw[shadowed={-{Latex[bend,length=6pt]},gray,line width=0.5ex}] ([xshift=0.3em,yshift=0.1em]ML.east)
    arc(190:370:1.5em) coordinate(aux0);
    \draw[shadowed={-{Latex[bend,length=6pt]},gray,line width=0.5ex}] ([yshift=0.1em]aux0)
    arc(10:190:1.5em);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks sharp!!! Really awesome. Thank you Marmot!!!